# Working with Django Foreign Keys, Linking to HTML page

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

I made a Django app for an online school, so I added a foreign key to link the databases Classes and Subjects, I just created A subject in the admin page, linked it into the wanted class, when trying to access it in HTML page I am just having the same subject on all classes, So i thing I used the foreign key the wrong way! how to do it? please help.

MODELS.py:

```
class Class(models.Model):
    image= models.ImageField(upload_to="images")
    name= models.CharField(max_length=200, default=1)
    title= models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Material(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=200, default=1)
    title= models.CharField(max_length=200)
    classes= models.ForeignKey(Class, default=1, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    {% load static %}    
    <head>    
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Name</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <nav>
                <div class="logo"><img src="static/images/Logo.png" width=50px></div>
                <ul class="navul">
                    <li class="navli"><a class="nava" href="404.html">حول الموقع</a></li>
                    <li class="navli"><a class="nava" href="404.html">المكتبة</a></li>
                    <li class="navli"><a class="nava" href="404.html">الدورات</a></li>
                    <li class="navli"><a class="nava" href="/classes">الصفوف</a></li>
                    <li class="navli"><a class="nava" href="/">الصفحة الرئيسية</a></li>


                    <button class="bt1"><a href="#">سجل دخول</a></button>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <div class="div1">
                <img src="static/images/Logo.png" width="90" class="logo2">
                <h1 class="t1">الصفوف</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="cardrow">
                {% for class in class.all %}
                <div class="cardcolumn">
                    <a href="{{% url 'material' class.id %}}"> 
                    <div class="card">
                    <img class="imgcls" src="{{ class.image.url }}">
                    <h1>{{ class.title }}</h1>
                    </div>
                    </a>
                </div>              
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

VIEWS.py:

```
def classes(reqest):
    Classes= Class.objects
    return render(reqest, 'classes/Classes.html', {"class":Classes})

def materials(reqest, classes_id):
    theclass= get_object_or_404(Class, pk=classes_id)
    Materials = Material.objects
    return render(reqest, 'classes/Materials.html', {"material":Materials}, {"classes":theclass})
```

I hope you understand me well, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use "class.material_set.all" to show all the material of the class

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    {% load static %}    
    <head>    
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Name</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <nav>
                <div class="logo"><img src="static/images/Logo.png" width=50px></div>
                <ul class="navul">
                    <li class="navli"><a class="nava" href="404.html">حول الموقع</a></li>
                    <li class="navli"><a class="nava" href="404.html">المكتبة</a></li>
                    <li class="navli"><a class="nava" href="404.html">الدورات</a></li>
                    <li class="navli"><a class="nava" href="/classes">الصفوف</a></li>
                    <li class="navli"><a class="nava" href="/">الصفحة الرئيسية</a></li>


                    <button class="bt1"><a href="#">سجل دخول</a></button>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <div class="div1">
                <img src="static/images/Logo.png" width="90" class="logo2">
                <h1 class="t1">الصفوف</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="cardrow">
                {% for class in class.all %}
                <div class="cardcolumn">
                    <a href="{{% url 'material' class.id %}}"> 
                    <div class="card">
                    <img class="imgcls" src="{{ class.image.url }}">
                    <h1>{{ class.title }}</h1>
                    <ul>
                         {% for material in class.material_set.all %}
                         <li> {{material}}</li>
                         {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                    </div>
                    </a>
                </div>              
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

For the detail you can read [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/)

And use this to send multiple context to template

```
def materials(request, classes_id):
    theclass= get_object_or_404(Class, pk=classes_id)
    Materials = Material.objects.all()
    context = {
        'classes': theclass,
        'material': Materials
    }
    return render(request, 'classes/Materials.html', context)
```

more about context you can read [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/api/#django.template.Context) and
when you use like this "Classes= Class.objects" it'll be object manager not queryset use this "Classes= Class.objects.all()" instead for queryset.